How to Execute Commands in C++ (Including “cd”) from Command Prompt using CreateProcess?
I’m working on a C++ program where I need to execute various commands, including the “cd” command, from within my code. I’ve tried using the CreateProcess function to run these commands, but I keep getting the message “Failed to execute a command” specifically when using “cd”.
Here’s a simplified version of my code snippet:
SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES sa;
    sa.nLength = sizeof(SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES);
    sa.bInheritHandle = TRUE;
    sa.lpSecurityDescriptor = nullptr;

    HANDLE hRead, hWrite;
    if (CreatePipe(&hRead, &hWrite, &sa, 0)) {
        STARTUPINFO si;
        PROCESS_INFORMATION pi;

        GetStartupInfo(&si);
        si.hStdError = hWrite;
        si.hStdOutput = hWrite;
        si.dwFlags |= STARTF_USESTDHANDLES;

        // Convert narrow string to wide string
        std::wstring wCommand(command.begin(), command.end());
        std::wstring wPath(current_path.begin(), current_path.end());

        if (CreateProcess(nullptr, 
                          const_cast<LPWSTR>(wCommand.c_str()), 
                          nullptr, 
                          nullptr, 
                          TRUE,
                          CREATE_NO_WINDOW, 
                          nullptr, 
                          const_cast<LPWSTR>(wPath.c_str()), 
                          &si, 
                          &pi)) 
        {
            CloseHandle(hWrite);
            WaitForSingleObject(pi.hProcess, INFINITE);

            DWORD bytesRead;
            char buffer[128];
            while (ReadFile(hRead, buffer, sizeof(buffer) - 1, &bytesRead, nullptr) != 0) {
                if (bytesRead == 0)
                    break;

                buffer[bytesRead] = '\0';
                result += buffer;
            }

            CloseHandle(hRead);
            CloseHandle(pi.hThread);
            CloseHandle(pi.hProcess);
        } else {
            result = "Failed to execute command";
        }
    } else {
        result = "Failed to create pipe";
    }

The code works well for most commands, but when I try to execute the “cd” command (e.g., command = "cd path/to/directory"), it fails with the error message “Failed to execute a command”. I suspect this is related to how the “cd” command interacts with the process.
How can I modify my code to handle the “cd” command correctly?
Are there any other considerations I should be aware of when executing commands from C++?
Note: This is optional to answer. Was just curios if I'm doing it right.
Since I'm using it for my code editor project, should I use a command line parsing for this(like "CLI11: Command line parser for C++11")? I currently just reading the input text and then execute them using CreatProcess.

Running cd in a subprocess defeats its purpose. It will change the working directory of that subprocess, then exit, leaving the parent's working directory unchanged. This is why cd is a shell builtin in all actually working shells (and cmd, which probably shouldn't be included in that definition).

If you want to change the current directory of your process you should call _chdir():  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/chdir-wchdir?view=msvc-170

In C++17, to change the current working directory, you can call std::filesystem::current_path.

so much of compex code.. but you're not aware that a) current directory is a property of process's context b) cd isn't a program , so you can't create a process

I see...So, what I did now is to separate the function that creates a process and a function that executes 'cd' command via 'std::filesystem::current_path(current_path);'. Separation was done by checking  by searching the input string if there is a 'cd'. That works well.
